# Temperature sensor showing really high temperature

Tags: hp, temperature, lm-sensors

I am using HP Probook 4740s and my laptop is running on Ubuntu 13.04. I am facing some heating issues but couldn't found out which hardware was actually causing the heating issue.I have installed Psensor and saw that temp6 is reading 127 Celsius which is about 260 Fahrenheit.

Can anyone tell me from which hardware I am getting this temp6 temperature reading ?

[image: temperatures]

[image: sensor's name]

Answer (score 1):

Install  the packages lm-sensors with

`sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`

then type

```
sensors
```

This give you a list of Adapters and the assigned sensors.

Answer (score 0):

The id field of psensor is starting with "lmsensor acpi". It means that psensor is retrieving the information of this sensor from the lmsensor lib which get it throw the ACPI. As ACPI is not really normalized and depends on manufacturer it is quite impossible to locate the corresponding component without the technical specifications of your specific HW.

More generally, if you want to identify the component, read http://wpitchoune.net/psensor/doc/faq.html#S_WhatIsTheSensor.

I guess that the temp6,7,8 temperatures never change, they are probably nothing else than default values meaning that there is no corresponding wired sensors. See http://wpitchoune.net/psensor/doc/faq.html#S_WrongTemperature.

Most components in a PC have trouble with temperature higher than 100C. At 127C you should observe a major HW failure or at least easily locate the component manually... My conclusion is that you can ignore temp6.

Obviously, a 0C is also impossible, if it does not change to a >0 when the PC is overloaded you can also ignore them.